# R - Dataframe manipulation

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, aggregate, data-manipulation

I’ve the following table as shown below

| Food | Fried | Boiled |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Egg | 3 | 2 |
| Fish | 5 | 3 |

The code for this Dataframe is

```
Names = c("Food", "Fried", "Boiled")
Egg = c("Egg", 3, 2)
Fish = c("Fish", 5, 3)
df = as.data.frame(rbind(Egg, Fish)) 
colnames(df) = Names; rownames(df) = NULL
```

I would like to manipulate the Dataframe into the following

| Food | Fried/Boiled |
| --- | --- |
| Egg | Fried |
| Egg | Fried |
| Egg | Fried |
| Egg | Boiled |
| Egg | Boiled |
| Fish | Fried |
| Fish | Fried |
| Fish | Fried |
| Fish | Fried |
| Fish | Fried |
| Fish | Boiled |
| Fish | Boiled |
| Fish | Boiled |

The 2nd column “Fried/Boiled” shows a new row for every value of fried and boiled respectively in the first table.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -Food) %>% type.convert(as.is = T) %>% uncount(value)
# A tibble: 13 x 2
   Food  name  
   <chr> <chr> 
 1 Egg   Fried 
 2 Egg   Fried 
 3 Egg   Fried 
 4 Egg   Boiled
 5 Egg   Boiled
 6 Fish  Fried 
 7 Fish  Fried 
 8 Fish  Fried 
 9 Fish  Fried 
10 Fish  Fried 
11 Fish  Boiled
12 Fish  Boiled
13 Fish  Boiled
```